# Surface tension Numerical problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, surface-tension

> A needle of length 5 cm can just rest on the surface of water of surface tension 0.073 N/m. Find the vertical force required to detach this floating needle from the surface of water.
> In this problem people solve using the formula
> $F=T×2L$. In which direction does the surface tension work vertically upward or downward?

Comment: Won't newtons law do the job?

Comment: The needle has two sides along its 'length,' so the total surface tension is twice of what you would expect ordinarily.

Comment: I am asking how is the tension force a vertical force? Isnt it parallel to the surface or inverted a bit?

Comment: By definition of the surface tension coefficient, it is the surface force normal to the object per unit length of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is that why the surface tension is acting vertically, it is because when you are pulling the needle out water will also lift up with the needle for some small distance, and in that situation the direction of force due to surface tension nearly vertical.

Hope this Helps.

P.S :I am not very sure about the correctness of this answer.

Edit: In similar situation when the needle rests on water the area on which it is resting gets depressed because of which the force acts vertically upward. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: So surface tension acts vertically downward?

Comment: Yes it is nearly vertical and you can assume it to be vertical for simplicity. (only during the process of taking it out of water)